# Printing vector in reverse order using range-based for loop

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, binary

I have this code that convert a decimal number into a binary one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void space(){ cout << endl << endl << endl; }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    system("color 1F");
    unsigned long int n, copy_n;
    vector<int> v;

    cout << "# Decimal:   "; cin >> n; cout << endl; copy_n = n;

    while (n != 0){
        if (n % 2 == 0){ v.push_back(0); }else{ v.push_back(1); }
        n = int(n / 2);}

    cout << endl << "# Binary:   ";

    reverse(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){cout << v.at(i);}


    space(); system("Pause"); return 0;
}
```

... and this ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void space(){ cout << endl << endl << endl; }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    system("color 1F");
    unsigned long int n, copy_n, nr = 0 ;
    cout << "# Decimal:  "; cin >> n; copy_n = n; cout << endl;

    while (copy_n != 0){ nr++; copy_n = int(copy_n / 2); }

    int* v = new int[nr];

    for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++){if (n % 2 == 0){ v[i] = 0; }else{ v[i] = 1; }n = int(n / 2);}

    cout << endl << "# Binary:  ";

    for (int i = nr-1; i >= 0;i--){cout << v[i] << "";}

    space(); system("Pause"); return 0;}
```

... and this ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

void space(){ cout << endl << endl << endl; }

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    system("color 1F");
    unsigned int n;
    cout << "# Decimal:  "; cin >> n; cout << endl;
    bitset<16>binary(n);
    cout << endl << "# Binary:  " << binary << endl;

    space(); system("Pause"); return 0;
}
```

But my question is:

How can I use reverse() function from algorithm and print the vector with range-based for loop

Ex: Decimal = 2

with

```
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){cout << v.at(i);}
```

program prints 10

with

```
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
for(auto i : v){cout<<v.at(i);}
```

program pritns 01

Why? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This for statement

```
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
for(auto i : v){cout<<v.at(i);}
```

is simply wrong.

The valid code will look like

```
reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
for(auto i : v){ cout << i;}
```

Also if you are paid for the number of symbols entered in the source code then this statement

```
if (n % 2 == 0){ v.push_back(0); }else{ v.push_back(1); }
```

looks very good because it contains many symbols. Otherwise it would be better to write

```
v.push_back( n % 2 );
```

Also in one of your programs you allocate dynamically an array

```
int* v = new int[nr];
```

but not free it. In this case it would be better to use smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`.

You could also try to write a recursive function. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<unsigned int> & dec_to_bin( std::vector<unsigned int> &v, 
                                        unsigned int x )
{
    const unsigned int Base = 2;
    static size_t n;

    unsigned int digit = x % Base;
    ++n;

    if ( x /= Base )
    {
        dec_to_bin( v, x );
    }
    else
    {
        v.reserve( n );
        n = 0;
    }

    v.push_back( digit );

    return v;
}

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int x = 0;
        std::cin >> x;

        if ( !x ) break;

        std::vector<unsigned int> v;

        dec_to_bin( v, x );

        for ( auto digit : v ) std::cout << digit;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter sequentially

```
15
7
3
1
0
```

then the program output will be

```
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 15
1111
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 7
111
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 3
11
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 1
1
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I know that I'm a stupid programmer , but I'm in high school and I'm passionate about programming. :)

Comment: it's 

cout << i; 

isn't it ?

Comment: @Andrei Paciurca  Thanks. It was a typo.:)

Comment: instead of `unique_ptr`-allocating a dynamic primitive array, why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: @Vlad Yeah! It's pretty cool , but I'm in 10th grade. I will learn about Recursive function, Devide Et Impera and Backtracking  in 11th grade. :D

Comment: @Andrei Paciurca  Write in your profile where you are from.:) It is always interesting to know who where lives.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Where are you from?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Is it hard to look through my profile?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :D